# My scrapping code skips new line - Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this code to scrape review text from IMDB. I want to retrieve the entire text from the review, but it skips every time there is a new line, for example:

> Saw an early screening tonight in Denver.
>
> I don't know where to begin. So I will start at the weakest link. The
> acting. Still great, but any passable actor could have been given any
> of the major roles and done a great job.

The code will only retrieve

> Saw an early screening tonight in Denver.

Here is my code:

```
reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.review-container')
first_review = reviews[0]
sel2 = Selector(text = first_review.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

rating_list = []
review_date_list = []
review_title_list = []
author_list = []
review_list = []

error_url_list = []
error_msg_list = []
reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.review-container')

for d in tqdm(reviews):
    try:
        sel2 = Selector(text = d.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        try:
            rating = sel2.css('.rating-other-user-rating span::text').extract_first()
        except:
            rating = np.NaN
        try:
            review = sel2.css('.text.show-more__control::text').get()
        except:
            review = np.NaN
        try:
            review_date = sel2.css('.review-date::text').extract_first()
        except:
            review_date = np.NaN    
        try:
            author = sel2.css('.display-name-link a::text').extract_first()
        except:
            author = np.NaN    
        try:
            review_title = sel2.css('a.title::text').extract_first()
        except:
            review_title = np.NaN

        rating_list.append(rating)
        review_date_list.append(review_date)
        review_title_list.append(review_title)
        author_list.append(author)
        review_list.append(review)

    except Exception as e:
        error_url_list.append(url)
        error_msg_list.append(e)
review_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'review_date':review_date_list,
    'author':author_list,
    'rating':rating_list,
    'review_title':review_title_list,
    'review':review_list
    })
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the specific part of code causing your problem? Also, it would be good if you provide an example of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.extract()` instead of `.get()` to extract all texts in the type of `list`. Then, you can use `.join()` to concatenate all texts into a single string.

```
review = sel2.css('.text.show-more__control::text').extract()
review = ' '.join(review)
```

output:

> 'For a teenager today, Dunkirk must seem even more distant than the
> Boer War did to my generation growing up just after WW2. For some,
> Christopher Nolan's film may be the most they will know about the
> event. But it's enough in some ways because even if it doesn't show
> everything that happened, maybe it goes as close as a film could to
> letting you know how it felt. "Dunkirk" focuses on a number of
> characters who are inside the event, living it ....'